# Socket.recv works but not gets or read?

Tags: ruby, networking, sockets

Hello I've been messing around with Sockets in Ruby some and came across some example code that I tried modifying and broke. I want to know why it's broken.

Server:

```
require "socket"  
dts = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 20000)  
loop do  
  Thread.start(dts.accept) do |s|  
  print(s, " is accepted\n")  
  s.write(Time.now)  
  print(s, " is gone\n")  
  s.close  
  end  
end
```

Client that works:

```
require 'socket'  
streamSock = TCPSocket.new( "127.0.0.1", 20000 )  
streamSock.print( "Hello\n" )  
str = streamSock.recv( 100 )  
print str  
streamSock.close
```

Client that is broken

```
require 'socket'  
streamSock = TCPSocket.new( "127.0.0.1", 20000 )  
streamSock.print( "Hello\n" )  
str=streamSock.read #this line modified
print str  
streamSock.close
```

I know that the `streamSock.print` is unnecessary (as well as the naming scheme being non-ruby) but I don't understand why `read` doesn't work while `recv` does, Why is this?

Comment: if anyone caught that in the broken example I had a different IP address. disregard that, I forgot to change it when copy-pasting

Comment: Take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147852/ruby-tcpsocket-write-doesnt-work-but-puts-does

Comment: Both your clients work fine for me. I'm on OS X Snow Leopard.

Comment: @mark Arch Linux and also tested on OpenBSD

Comment: I have a similar issue here. `socket.read` never receives any response. `socket.recv(4096)` works great. Any chance `sockert.read` expects a `\r\n`?

Answer (score 1):

A very subtle race condition. Your are closing the connection server side without waiting for the client to complete. If your client finish before s.close, you will get the right answer, if the server finish first, you will get Errno::ECONNRESET. Which mean the client lost the connection while working.

A simple workaround will be to wait a fixed amount of time before closing the connection server side. Just enough time to let the client finish.